# python:find a ascending/decreasing elements in a list without using loop

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list, I need to find two lists in list 'a', in a increasing/decreasing order, respectively.

```
a=[4,2,6,5,2,6,9,7,10,1,2,1]
```

The output should be a list :

```
b=[4,6,9,10] # in an ascending order
```

and

```
c=[4,2,1] # in a decreasing order , c[-1] is the first '1' in list a, c[1] is the first '2' in list a.
```

Is there a possible way to do it without using loop (I have solved it using a loop)? As a have a large dataset, using loop would be slow. So I am looking for a faster way if possible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello, could you explain more how your ouput lists are calculated ?

Comment: why isn't the answer to the first question `4,5,6,7,10`, that has 5 elements while your example only has 4

Comment: Just given the list, I don't see how you could possibly find these sequences without iterating over the list. Are there any other reasons to avoid a loop besides "using loop would be slow"?

Comment: So let us please see your approach with the loops. Would be of great help to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: what do you mean by `the output should be list` n show `b=[4,6,9,10]` ??  where did `1, 2, 7 ` disappear  - these are there in your `a` . Based on what condition should those be `filtered out` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .sort() method. If no parameters are entered then it automatically sorts the list in ascending order. For descending just do .sort(reverse=True).

```
b = a.sort()
#ascending

c = a.sort(reverse=True)
#descending
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Could you precise your problem :

- Do you want to find the longest ascending/decreasing sub list ? In this case your problem has something to do with dynamic programming, and I think you'll need more than one loop...
- If you don't want your sub-lists to be maximal, maybe you can set a limit on the length of your lists b and c to do it faster.

  - If you have other hypothesis on your list, for instance, you know its max and its min, you can stop your calcul when you reach the max (only if you want your lists to be strictly decreasing/ascending).

I hope it is usefull for you :)

Answer (score 0):

To precise my question, the following is how I get these two lists:

```
b=[];c=[];
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i==0:
        b.append(a[i])
    elif a[i]>b[-1]:
        b.append(a[i])
for i in range(len(a)):
   if i==0:
       c.append(a[i])
   elif a[i]<c[-1]:
       c.append(a[i])
```